# How to save the last output in variable when hit KeyboardInterrupt subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, kali-linux

I am completely new to the subprocess module. And I was trying to automate the deauthentication attack commands. When I run `airodump-ng wlan0mon` as you know it looks for the APs nearby and the connected clients to it.

Now when I try to run this command using lets suppose `p = subprocess.run(["airmon-ng","wlan0mon"], capture_output=True)` in Python as you know this command runs until the user hits Ctrl+C, so it should save the last output when user hits Ctrl+C in the variable but instead I get error which is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Deauth.py", line 9, in <module>
    p3 = subprocess.run(["airodump-ng","wlan0"], capture_output=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 491, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1024, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1866, in _communicate
    ready = selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 415, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am sorry. I'll avoid it next time. Thanks for editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Python's [error handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html). Catch any `KeyboardInnterrupt`s (within your subprocess function) using `try` and `except` statements like so:

```
def stuff(things):
  try:
    # do stuff
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    return last_value
```

Comment: Would you explain it a little bit more because I don't understand it. May be you can write it for the command I provided in my question. By the way thanks for the answer.